# Why does the one-sided T-test reject the Null Hypothesis while the two-sided doesn't?

Tags: t-test

I'm not that familiar with statistics, especially not with `T-tests`, however I need to apply a `T-test` for my `dataset`.
My `dataset` is basically an observation of productivity over several weeks, where week 1 and 2 are considered as  phase 1 and week 3 as phase 2. **I'm comparing if there's a productivity increase between phase 1 and phase 2**.

Now, the `one-sided T-test` rejects the `Null hypothesis` (with 90%), where the `two sided` does not reject the `Null hypothesis` (between 80% and 90%).

Could someone explain to me, what this behavior means and which result I should focus more on?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279162/unbiased-hypothesis-test-what-does-it-mean-actually/279199#279199

Answer (score 1):

Let say the significance level $ \alpha $ is 0.05

For a one tailed t-test, the hypothesis is rejected when the test statistic > the 95% quantile (or less than 5% quantile depends on your alternative). While for a two tailed t-test, the hypothesis is rejected when test statistic > the 97.5% qunatile or < 2.5 quantile.

In both case, the type one error is 5% , but when your test statistic lies between 95% and 97.5% quantile, then you will see rejetion for one-tailed test but not two-tailed test.

Comment: Mmh okay, so does that mean the dataset is somewhat statistically significant? Or how do I need to interpret this result?

Comment: @Scorpia The best practise for hypothesis testing is you formulate your hypothesis before looking at the dataset. You could formulate your hypothesis in this way: If you want to test whether the productivity changes but you are not sure whether it would increase or decrease, then you should use a 2 tail test. In constrats, if you guess there should be an increase, you should use 1 tail test.